# How to effectively compare all models accuracy

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I've splitted the training data and initialized 11 classifier models which I now want to compare.

I'm running VS Code on Ubuntu 18.04.

I've tried:

```
# Prepare lists
models = [ran, knn, log, xgb, gbc, svc, ext, ada, gnb, gpc, bag]         
scores = []

# Sequentially fit and cross validate all models
for mod in models:
    mod.fit(X_train, y_train)
    acc = cross_val_score(mod, X_train, y_train, scoring = 
    "accuracy", cv = 10)
scores.append(acc.mean())

# Creating a table of results, ranked highest to lowest
results = pd.DataFrame({
    'Model': ['Random Forest', 'K Nearest Neighbour', 'Logistic 
     Regression', 'XGBoost', 'Gradient Boosting', 'SVC', 'Extra 
     Trees', 'AdaBoost', 'Gaussian Naive Bayes', 'Gaussian Process', 
     'Bagging Classifier'],
     'Score': scores})
```

which returns on the last part:

> ValueError: arrays must all be same length

I've counted that 2x and indeed there're 11 models.

What am I missing?

Comment: *Where exactly* does the error pop up? Please include the full error trace...

Comment: @desertnaut The error is returned for the pandas dataframe.

Comment: Did you check the answer below (i.e. move `scores.append()` inline with the rest of your `for` loop)?

Comment: None of the answers good enough to accept?

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is an indentation error in your code, see the edited code below. In your code if you do `len(scores)` you will get `1` because only the last value is getting added as the append is called outside the loop.

```
# Prepare lists
models = [ran, knn, log, xgb, gbc, svc, ext, ada, gnb, gpc, bag]         
scores = []

# Sequentially fit and cross validate all models
for mod in models:
    mod.fit(X_train, y_train)
    acc = cross_val_score(mod, X_train, y_train, scoring = 
    "accuracy", cv = 10)
    scores.append(acc.mean())
```

Comment: Nope, that's not the issue. The error is returned for the last part of the code, pandas dataframe.

Comment: @StanislavJirak This does not mean that the answer is wrong; as your code is, `scores` turns out to be a single-element list (i.e. you append only the last `acc.mean()` from your for loop), which can indeed produce the error you report further downstream; please **include the full error trace**...

Comment: @StanislavJirak, you can check the length of `scores` in your code, which will be `1`. You are trying to make a Dataframe with `11` entries in one column and `1` entry in another, which throws error. Pandas throws error, that error occurs because the length of the columns are not correct.

Comment: I see now. But how do I create an empty array with 11 columns? I tried the code.

Comment: What do you mean? Why create any empty array? The suggested remedy here resolves your issue, see also my answer for corroboration...,

Answer (score 2):

Having already upvoted the previous answer, I proceed to *demonstrate* that the error is indeed due to your `score.append()` being outside your `for` loop:

We don't need to actually fit any model; we can simulate the situation with the following modifications of your code, which do not change the essence of the issue:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

models = ['ran', 'knn', 'log', 'xgb', 'gbc', 'svc', 'ext', 'ada', 'gnb', 'gpc', 'bag']         
scores = []
cv=10

# Sequentially fit and cross validate all models
for mod in models:
    acc = np.array([np.random.rand() for i in range(cv)]) # simulate your accuracy here
scores.append(acc.mean()) # as in your code, i.e outside the for loop

# Create a dataframe of results
results = pd.DataFrame({
    'Model': ['Random Forest', 'K Nearest Neighbour', 'Logistic Regression', 'XGBoost', 'Gradient Boosting',  
    'SVC', 'Extra Trees', 'AdaBoost', 'Gaussian Naive Bayes', 'Gaussian Process', 'Bagging Classifier'],
    'Score': scores})
```

Unsurprizingly, this essentially replicates your error:

```
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

because, as already argued in the other answer, your `scores` list has a single element, i.e. the `acc.mean()` from only the *last* iteration of your loop:

```
len(scores)
# 1
scores
# [0.47317491043203785]
```

hence pandas complains, as it cannot fill an 11-row dataframe...

Moving `scores.append()` inside the `for` loop, as already suggested in the other answer, resolves the issue:

```
for mod in models:
    acc = np.array([np.random.rand() for i in range(cv)])
    scores.append(acc.mean()) # moved inside the loop

# Create a dataframe of results
results = pd.DataFrame({
    'Model': ['Random Forest', 'K Nearest Neighbour', 'Logistic Regression', 'XGBoost', 'Gradient Boosting',  
    'SVC', 'Extra Trees', 'AdaBoost', 'Gaussian Naive Bayes', 'Gaussian Process', 'Bagging Classifier'],
    'Score': scores})
print(results)
# output:
                   Model     Score
0          Random Forest  0.492364
1    K Nearest Neighbour  0.624068
2    Logistic Regression  0.613653
3                XGBoost  0.536488
4      Gradient Boosting  0.484195
5                    SVC  0.381556
6            Extra Trees  0.274922
7               AdaBoost  0.509297
8   Gaussian Naive Bayes  0.362866
9       Gaussian Process  0.606538
10    Bagging Classifier  0.393950
```

You may also want to keep in mind that you don't need the `model.fit()` part in your code - `cross_val_score` does all the necessary fitting itself...

Comment: Good explaination. @StanislavJirak hope you understood what is wrong with your code.